# Is it possible to get the label or describe from an SObjectTypeToken?

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, sobjecttype

In my controller, I have some `SObjectType` property:

```
public SObjectType myProperty { get; private set; }
```

**I want to get the label (or better yet the entire describe) of this object in Visualforce** without modifying my Apex to add any additional properties. Is it possible?

In my current use case, this property is surfaced as part of a larger feature and can't be easily modified or extended.

---

**Attempt 1:**

```
{!myProperty.describe.label}
```

**Error 1:**

> Unknown property 'SObjectTypeToken.describe'

---

**Attempt 2:**

```
{!$ObjectType[myProperty].label}
```

**Error 2:**

> Incorrect parameter type for subscript. Expected Text, received SObjectType

---

**Attempt 3:**

```
{!TEXT(myProperty)}
```

**Error 3:**

> Incorrect parameter type for function 'TEXT()'. Expected DateTime, received SObjectType

---

**Attempt 4:**

```
{!myProperty.label}
```

**Error 4:**

> Unknown property 'SObjectTypeToken.label'

Comment: Great timing on your question. I'm working on something where I've been struggling with the similar issues! +1  @Ronnie answer is the kind of solution that I came up with which ultimately worked for me. Great addition with Eric's comments that I'll find helpful as I continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller:

```
public class Test{
    public Schema.SObjectType myProperty { get; private set; }


    public Test(){
        myProperty = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get( 'Account' );
    }
}    

<apex:page controller="Test">
      <apex:variable value="{!myProperty}" var="prop" />
      <apex:variable value="{!prop[ 'describe' ]}" var="field" />
      {!field}
</apex:page>
```

Above is an output of the describe result which will get the properties that you will want to see - you can use this to pull back the items you need by their keys ['label'], ['name']...

[image: Display the object type result on the page]

```
<apex:page controller="Test">
  <apex:variable value="{!myProperty}" var="prop" />
  <apex:variable value="{!prop[ 'describe' ]}" var="field" />
  {!field['localName']}
</apex:page>
```

Here you will see that you can output the value by its key in the describe map

[image: Display the propertys by their Keys in the describe map]

**Eric Added**

Also you can do away with the variables and just do `{!prop['describe']['localName']}`

Comment: Edited this response to use just the SObjectType in your controller - i set to account for example purposes - try it out

Comment: @AdrianLarson Well all be d&mned.....Never would have thought that an SObjectType token would have a key of `describe` that could be pulled into a VF page.  **NICE ONE**

Comment: - of course - i just used variables to show the multiple indexes and he can use them however he chooses can do the same if you're storing the fields on the backend in a map too - you can use the keys in a repeat and get the tokens to each and  list them as well  - i don't really see so many applications where doing this on the VF is very useful - but i can be wrong

Comment: yea, I just added it for those that come later and may not realize it. Feel free to update, remove, etc as you see fit. Nice answer. Using `['describe']` seems so obvious now lol

Comment: no need - nice addition

Comment: Nice answer guys! I nearly posted a similar question earlier this week.

Comment: this merits making a documentation suggestion to the VF doc team

Comment: I didn't even see this answer (nor bounty) get added. I was busy climbing some mountains and didn't have any internet access for a few days. When I got back, didn't see any notifications. What a pleasant surprise! This one is a game changer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw this out there as an option, even though you desire to not modify your Apex - since the `$ObjectType` global variable requires a string for its key:

```
public SObjectType myProperty { get; private set; }

public String getObjectName() {
    // check for null & stuff
    return myProperty.getDescribe().getName();
}
```

and then in VF

```
<apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType[objectName].label}"/>
```

Comment: It's a collection though, so this particular approach doesn't work great for me. Right now I've got a shadow `Map<SObjectType, DescribeSObjectResult>` property, but I'm trying to find a way to get rid of that. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use $ObjectType, but you do need to modify your code:

```
public SObjectType myProperty { get; private set; }
public String myPropertySObjectType { get { return myproperty+''; } }
```

---

```
{!$ObjectType[myPropertySObjectType].label}
```

Comment: Essentially the same as what Mark proposes. Same pitfall for my needs. It's a collection.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You need to have a String, ultimately, if you want to skip the describe in Apex Code.  Without seeing more code, I'm not sure that we'll be able to give you much more than variants of the same.

Answer (score 1):

**See Ronnie's answer**

<strike>A bit heavy Handed but using JS you can get the label from the REST API then you could use JS to put the label where you need it....and it requires no change to your Apex code</strike>

```
<apex:page controller="[YOUR CONTROLLER}">
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
<script>
    var t = '{!objectName}';

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $.ajax('/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/' + t + '/describe/',
        {
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Set the OAuth header from the session ID
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_ID}');
          },
          success: function(response) {
              console.log('The Label is: ' + response.label);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Oops - what went wrong?
            alert(jqXHR.status + ': ' + errorThrown);
          }
        }
      );
    });

</script>

</apex:page>
```